# Image Not Displaying in Some Pages in Django Template

Tags: python, django, image, sorl-thumbnail

This is file structure:

myApp/
    mediafiles/
        photos
    mySite/
        templates/
            mySite/
                index.html
                images.html
                profile.html

My images get saved to `mediafiles/photos` with these settings:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS, MEDIA_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')]
MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
```

I have four `urls`:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^newimage/$', views.newImage, name='profile_photo'),
url(r'^user/(?P<user_name>\w+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
url(r'^books/(?P<book_id>\d+)/(?P<book_name>[-\w]+)/$', views.book_profile, name='book_profile'),
```

Using `sorl-thumbnail`:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
#the image tag below display my image correctly
<img src=".{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">

url(r'^newimage/$', views.newImage, name='profile_photo'),
#the image tag below display my image correctly
<img src="..{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">

url(r'^user/(?P<user_name>\w+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
#all the image tags below display my image correctly
<img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
<img src=".{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
<img src="...{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I do it correctly?

Comment: Tell which part is creating problem .. ?

Comment: @rajasimon: The third `url`. As I stated in the question. Image doesn't display there. It displays a square box.

Comment: Ok.. Did you check the created cache image in cache folder ?

Comment: @rajasimon: it's there. Even the images.

Comment: Seems you may have sorl installation issue ..

Comment: @rajasimon: You can't help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65759/discussion-between-rajasimon-and-yax).